# extending shouldjs methods (mocha + node)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, mocha.js, should.js

In my [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/)/[should](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/) functional tests I find myself often writing 
`el.is(':visible').should.eql true`

Since I do it so much I was thinking it might make sense to extend `should` so I can do something like this: `el.should.beVisible()`

That would allow me to change the internals, too, like say:

`beVisible = -> this.is(':visible') or this.hasClass('visible')` - in case I am using CSS to toggle the visibility. Or, say I decide to drop jQuery in favour of a different dom manipulation library, this would allow my tests to stay the same.

This is just an example - I often find myself wanting to repeat specific "should" assertions, but I am not sure how to extend it. How do I do this? Is it a bad idea?

The only thing I've tried so far is `should.prototype.beSomething = -> console.log 'does not work'`